# https in Broken in Chrome with Store

Tags: expresso-store

When I test my new story (express-store) in chrome and I get to the checkout part and the https kicks in the style sheet breaks. and  the yellow lock icon appears in the address bar. The images load on the page but not the styles. However, in Safari or Firefox this does NOT happen and it lets me complete the purchase. Running the last version of both EE and Express-Store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your CSS/JS is not being loaded from a secure URL. Check your developer console to see where they are being loaded from.

Comment: how do I make it secure it is loading from  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{stylesheet=store_osd/bootstrap}" />
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='{stylesheet=site/stylesheet}' />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{stylesheet=store_osd/custom}" /> thanks

Comment: There are a couple of ways that you can achieve that. The simplest way would be to use relative paths for your JS/CSS so it will load based upon the current URL. You can also take a look at https://exp-resso.com/blog/post/2011/08/securing-your-expressionengine-website-with-https or http://feistygoat.com/blog/2010/10/force-ssl-in-expressionengine/ for more info